# validates_uniqueness_of with conditions is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

sorry for my english,

I have this validation on my model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :price, scope: [:brand, :establishment, :presentation, :user], conditions: -> { where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day) }
```

And this is my factory and test for it.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :price do
    association :establishment
    association :presentation
    association :brand
    association :user
    price 9.99
  end
end
```

---

```
it "is invalid on duplicated by date" do
  price = create(:price)
  expect(build(:price, price.attributes)).to have(1).errors
end
```

And I am getting...

```
1) Price is invalid on duplicated by date
    Failure/Error: expect(build(:price, price.attributes)).to have(1).errors
      expected 1 errors, got 0
```

**Why?**

Comment: Do you have the validation on `Price` model?

Comment: Yes, I do. The validation is on Price model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, my error was on a database conception, I had a float type for price field, I changed it to decimal type to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

validation errors get added to new objects(unsaved) only when you call `valid?` on the object

```
it "is invalid on duplicated by date" do
  price = create(:price)
  new_price = build(:price, price.attributes)
  new_price.valid?
  expect(new_price).to have(1).errors
end
```